# How to create a uniswap pool on goerli with two custom created tokens, tokenA and tokenB?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, evm, nodejs, goerli

I am trying to create a node script to create a pool and add liquidity to uniswap with two custom tokenA and tokenB by utilizing the goerli network.

I created the pool using,

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

const UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";

const GOERLI_PROVIDERS = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.INFURA_URL_GOERLI);
const WALLET_ADDRESS = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS;
const WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const sidCoinA = "0xaa8C9c9E55b072306Dd3669F40A06DAf24e9b668";
const sidCoinB = "0x567DdF6FC05Cb3fa3E045b27EE18323037e7555F";

async function createPool() {
  try {
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(GOERLI_PROVIDERS);

    const url = `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS}&apikey=${process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const abi = JSON.parse(res.data.result);

    const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
      UNISWAP_V3_FACTORY_ADDRESS,
      abi,
      GOERLI_PROVIDERS
    );

    const pool = await factoryContract.getPool(sidCoinA, sidCoinB, 500);

    // if (pool != ethers.constants.AddressZero) {
    //   console.log("Pool already exists at address:", pool);
    //   return pool;
    // }

    console.log("Creating pool...");
    const tx = await factoryContract.connect(connectedWallet).createPool(sidCoinA, sidCoinB, 500, { gasLimit: 5000000 });
    const receipt = await tx.wait();

    console.log("Pool created with address:", receipt.logs[0].address);
    return receipt.logs[0].address;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

createPool();
```

This was the code to add liquidity

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const { Token } = require('@uniswap/sdk-core');
const { Pool, Position, nearestUsableTick } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk');
const { abi: IUniswapV3PoolABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json');
const { abi: NonfungiblePositionManagerABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json');
const ERC20ABI = require('./ERC20ABI.json');

require('dotenv').config()

const WALLET_ADDRESS = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS;
const WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

const poolAddress = "0x34b2A61596A27B7b626C995a594E3706D834a8A0"
const positionManagerAddress = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88"


const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.INFURA_URL_GOERLI);

const sidCoinA = 'sidCoinA'
const symbol0  = 'sidCoinA'
const decimals0 = 18
const address0 = "0xaa8C9c9E55b072306Dd3669F40A06DAf24e9b668"

const sidCoinB = 'sidCoinB'
const symbol1  = 'sidCoinB'
const decimals1 = 18
const address1 = "0x567DdF6FC05Cb3fa3E045b27EE18323037e7555F"

const chainID = 5
const sidCoinAToken = new Token(chainID, address0, decimals0, symbol0, sidCoinA)
const sidCoinBToken = new Token(chainID, address1, decimals1, symbol1, sidCoinB)

const NonfungiblePositionManagerContract = new ethers.Contract(positionManagerAddress, NonfungiblePositionManagerABI, provider);

const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(poolAddress, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

async function getPoolData(poolContract) {
   const [tickSpacing, fee, liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
       poolContract.tickSpacing(),
       poolContract.fee(),
       poolContract.liquidity(),
       poolContract.slot0()
   ])

   return{
       tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
       fee: fee,
       liquidity: liquidity,
       sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
       tick: slot0[1],
   }
}

async function main() {
   const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract) 

   const sidUniPool = new Pool(sidCoinA, sidCoinB, poolData.fee, poolData.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), poolData.liquidity, poolData.tick)

   const tickSpacing = await poolContract.tickSpacing()
   const tickLower = nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick - tickSpacing * 2, tickSpacing)
   const tickUpper = nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick + tickSpacing * 2, tickSpacing) 
   const position = new Position({
       pool: sidUniPool,
       liquidity: ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.01', 18),
       tickLower,
       tickUpper,
   })

   const wallet = new ethers.wallet(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY)
   const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider)

   const approvalAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.01', 18).toString()
   const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(address0, ERC20ABI, provider)
   await tokenContract.connect(connectedWallet).approve(positionManagerAddress, approvalAmount)

   const approvalAmount1 = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.01', 18).toString()
   const tokenContract1 = new ethers.Contract(address1, ERC20ABI, provider)
   await tokenContract1.connect(connectedWallet).approve(positionManagerAddress, approvalAmount1)

   const { amount0: amount0Desired, amount1: amount1Desired } = position.mintAmounts

   params = {
       token0: sidCoinAToken.address,
       token1: sidCoinBToken.address,
       fee: sidUniPool.fee,
       tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tickSpacing, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
       tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tickSpacing, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
       tickLower: position.tickLower,
       tickUpper: position.tickUpper,
       amount0Desired: amount0Desired.toString(),
       amount1Desired: amount1Desired.toString(),
       amount0Min: amount0Desired.toString(),
       amount1Min: amount1Desired.toString(),
       recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
       deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10,
   }

   NonfungiblePositionManagerContract.connect(connectedWallet).mint(params,{gasLimit: 1000000}).then((res) => {console.log(res)})
}

main();
```

This is giving me a price bound error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The steps I would take to solve this problem:

1. Get the smart contracts.
   Basic ERC20 Tokens can be implemented with OpenZeppelins [ERC20](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/) wizard.
   For Uniswap, you need to interact with the UniswapFactory and with the created UniswapPair.
   You can find the Factory source code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f#code) and the Pair source code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3fe2b8eabd4ba1708bae4b2b8a096e49fc15a71a#code)
2. Deploy the contracts.
3. Interact with the contracts. 
   Here you would want to create instances of the contract and call the desired functions.

Frameworks such as Truffle and Hardhat ease the process of smart contract development. Hardhat provides a [quick start](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#quick-start) for contract deployment and scripts for interaction and testing. You can use them as a starting point.